# Mockito checked exception is invalid for this method

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, mockito

I'm getting the error `Checked exception is invalid for this method` when trying to use this mock:

```
InitialContext mockContext;
mockContext = mock(InitialContext.class);
when((DataSource) mockContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/foo")).thenThrow(new ConnectionFactoryException("test")); // <-- Fails on this line

@Test
public void shouldThrowExceptionIfDataSourceDoesNotExist() throws ConnectionFactoryException {
    assertThatExceptionOfType(ConnectionFactoryException.class)
        .isThrownBy(() -> { new DataSourceFactory(mockContext).getDataSource("foo"); })
        .withMessage("Unable to find jdbc/foo");
}
```

Class I'm trying to test:

```
public class DataSourceFactory {

    // Dependencies to be injected
    private InitialContext context;

    public DataSourceFactory(InitialContext context) throws ConnectionFactoryException {

        if(context == null) {
            throw new ConnectionFactoryException("context can't be null");
        }

        this.context = context;
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource(String dataSourceName) throws ConnectionFactoryException {

        if(dataSourceName == null) {
            throw new ConnectionFactoryException("dataSourceName can't be null");
        }

        // Ensure we have the correct syntax for the datasource name
        if(!dataSourceName.startsWith("jdbc/")) {
            dataSourceName = "jdbc/" + dataSourceName;
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("java:comp/env/" + dataSourceName);
            DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:comp/env/" + dataSourceName);
            return dataSource;
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new ConnectionFactoryException("Unable to find " + dataSourceName, e);
        }
    }
}
```

I know I've read that I shouldn't mock objects I don't own, but I can't figure out how to test the `getDataSource()` method without mocking `InitialContext`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lookup` indeed doesn't throw a `ConnectionFactoryException` - your code does. Instead, you should throw the correct exception - a [`NamingException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/NamingException.html), and test that your code handles it as expected (i.e., throws up a ConnectionFactoryException`):

```
when(mockContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/foo"))
    .thenThrow(new NamingException("test"));
```

Comment: What I was not understanding is that you need to force the exception in your code by STUBBING the right conditions, THEN assertThrows(YourException.class, () -> { service.methodThrowingException()));, this answer gave it to me, after reading and attempting a lot of things.